# c# webclient blank page

Tags: c#, download, web-scraping, webclient

I have the following code and I am getting some strange behavior.
 I am trying to download the following webpage, most of the time it just returns a blank page but sometimes it will work once but then the same search won't work a 2nd time. Not really sure why, I have the same code working for other sites and its working just fine.

http://tpb.pirateparty.org.uk/search/test/0/99/0
'test' is the search text that will change depending on the search.

```
private static string DownloadHtml()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var data = client.OpenRead("http://tpb.pirateparty.org.uk/search/test/0/99/0");
    var reader = new StreamReader(data);
    var html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    data.Close();
    reader.Close();
    return html;
}
```

Does anyone know something that I might be missing?

Comment: I am afraid jay, but it seems like your code is working fine in my machine. I have run it too many times. Same HTML every time. You might want to check the TIMEOUT property of the webclient. That will help. It is set in NS.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Sheena's answer: another possibility is that you don't properly `Dispose` the Http connection.

You could simply do:

```
return new WebClient().DownloadString(
    "http://tpb.pirateparty.org.uk/search/test/0/99/0");
```

which takes care of all these details, or if you prefer to have access to the underlying stream, then do this:

```
var client = new WebClient();

using (var data = client.OpenRead(
    "http://tpb.pirateparty.org.uk/search/test/0/99/0"))
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(data);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be to do with the fact that your request to the site says 'I am a script' instead of 'i am a human behind a browser'. If doing the search in your browser repeatedly works fine then the solution is just to set headers in your request.

So use wireshark or something to see what headers are sent when you use your browser (you should look at the User-Agent field) and then just use a command like the following to set the header.

```
myWebClient.Headers.Add("some_header_name","the_value");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it would seem like you are correct with the headers.

Comment: I found ppukuid=UPEx9FB6x1mWVkwhAxBMAg== as a cookie. It changes on each refresh, I can get the first page of search results to load now, although when I move to page 2 it returns blank. I am guessing as the id is wrong? Is there any way to get passed this?

Comment: You cant just copy cookie stuff around, I think it would be best to keep track of cookie info and update it on your requests as you go